# kafka -> storm -> flink : unexpected block data

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-flink

Im moving a topology from storm to flink. The topology has been reduced to `KafkaSpout->Bolt`. The bolt is just counting packets and not trying to decode them.

The compiled .jar is submitted to flink via `flink -c <entry point> <path to .jar>` and hits the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Call to registerInputOutput() of invokable failed
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:529)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot instantiate user function.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperator(StreamConfig.java:190)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.registerInputOutput(StreamTask.java:174)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:526)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1365)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:294)
        at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:255)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperator(StreamConfig.java:175)
        ... 3 more
```

My question(s):

1. Did I miss a configuration step w/re the **KafkaSpout**? This was working when used in vanilla-storm.
2. Are there specific versions of the storm libraries that I need to use? I'm including 0.9.4 with my build.
3. Something else that I might have missed?

Should I be using the storm **KafkaSpout** or would I be better served by writing my own using the flink [KafkaSource](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/streaming_guide.html#apache-kafka)?

---

EDIT:

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

### Topology:

```
BrokerHosts brokerHosts = new ZkHosts(configuration.getString("kafka/zookeeper"));

SpoutConfig kafkaConfig = new SpoutConfig(brokerHosts, configuration.getString("kafka/topic"), "/storm_env_values", "storm_env_DEBUG");
FlinkTopologyBuilder builder = new FlinkTopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("environment", new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig), 1);
builder.setBolt("decode_bytes", new EnvironmentBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping("environment");
```

### Init:

```
FlinkLocalCluster cluster = new FlinkLocalCluster(); // replaces: LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("env_topology", conf, buildTopology());
```

The bolt is based on [BaseRichBolt](https://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/topology/base/BaseRichBolt.html). The **execute()** fn just logs the presence of any packet to debug. No other code in there.

Comment: Storm's KafkaSpout was never tested in Flink yet. Can you mail me your code so I can have a look.

Comment: Not sure how to contact you. Updated post with some code snips.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look. Btw: https://github.com/mjsax ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had look at this. There is one issues right now but I got it working locally. You can apply this hot fixed to your code and build the compatibility layer by yourself.

1. `KafkaSpout` registers metrics. However, metrics are currently not supported by the compatibility layer. You need to remove the exception in `FlinkTopologyContext.registerMetric(...)` and just return `null`. (There is already a open PR that work on the integration of metrics, thus I don't want to push this hot fix into master branch)
2. Furhtermore, you need to add some configuration parameters to your query manually:

I just made up some values here:

```
Config c = new Config();
List<String> zkServers = new ArrayList<String>();
zkServers.add("localhost");
c.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, zkServers);
c.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181);
c.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT, 30);
c.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 30);
c.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_RETRY_TIMES, 3);
c.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_RETRY_INTERVAL, 5);
```

3. You need to add some additional dependencies to your project:

Additionally to `flink-storm` you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This works for me, using **Kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1** and `FlinkLocalCluster` execute within Eclipse.

It also works in a local Flink cluster started via `bin/start-local-streaming.sh`. For this, using `bin/flink run` command, you need to use `FlinkSubmitter` instead of `FlinkLocalCluster`. Furthermore, you need the following dependencies for your jar:

```
<include>org.apache.storm:storm-kafka</include>
<include>org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10</include>
<include>org.apache.curator:curator-client</include>
<include>org.apache.curator:curator-framework</include>
<include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
<include>com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core</include>
```